# Implementing LINQ provider

Tags: c#, linq

I'm currently implementing a LINQ provider for my own educational purposes. I have managed to get `Count()` extension to work recently, so far so good.

Now my question is not a cry for help, but just a request for some clarification.

There are two interfaces to be implemented in order to create the provider: `IQueryProvider` and something like `IOrderedQueryable<>`. MSDN makes clear how one implements them, but one point is still confusing me.

**Why these interfaces are implemented by separate classes**, even though each `IOrderedQueryable` instance refers own `IQueryProvider` instance and both objects actually (indirectly) refer the same data?

Do they really need to be separated?

Furthermore. I am able to combine them like this: `class Source<RowContract> : IQueryProvider, IOrderedQueryable<RowContract>` - in order to simplify type information access. This implementation works properly now and looks more simple and clear than "separate-classes" approach.

I am wondering if there is a flaw in my combined implementation. Or, maybe it's valid?

Any explanation would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Not an answer, but just in case you didn't find it yet: [LINQ: Building an IQueryable provider series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2008/11/18/linq-links.aspx)

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt I am still confused. The link says `IQueryable` and `IQueryProvider` are separated since "Beta 2" but it does not say why would one implement them separately. The link is useful for furher work, though. Thanks!

Comment: I honestly wouldn't know. I set out to write a Linq provider at least once a year for fun and educational purposes, and always end up not completing them, because of lack of time, loss of interest, work, in short: Life ;) Good luck :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) IQueryProvider is focused on creating and executing the query.  Whereas IQueryable is the thing being queried.  Rolling it all together may put similar code together, but it ultimately doesn't respect separation of concerns.

Comment: Seems to be true. By the way, I have rolled back my implementation to "separate-classes" approach recently. My question was probably a result of some misunderstanding of what LINQ is. Thank you!